# How does cocoapods multiple private repo using a same repo.git

Tags: cocoapods

I have several private repo,such as A,B,C,D and the remote git url is https://127.0.0.1/repo/repo.git . How can i push A,B,C,D to the same remote git url(https://127.0.0.1/repo/repo.git) ? then local git just like .cocoapods/repos/master/Specs content, such as

├── Specs 
    └── A 
    └── B 
    └── C 
    └── D 
if it done , how can i make the profile for installing.

Comment: add all your pod-spec files in the main directory for the repo and set the git URL  of your pod-spec to the same directory of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the pod-spec file of your cocoa-pod to the main repo folder and update the pod-spec source files path.

More details:
to create a cocoa-pod you need two steps

```
pod lib create POD_NAME 
///this command runs in terminal to create for you a library with example option and many other things

 pod lib lint POD_NAME.podspec 
/// validate your spec file, check syntax and your files.
```

You could skip the first command and create your pod-spec file manually || copy it from any repo
then update it, add your code to your cocoa-pod folder, set the git repo in your pod-spec
make sure the git-repo have the pod-spec file in the main directory

You will find a complete example with Demo application in this project
https://github.com/abuzeid-ibrahim/DevPods